# USB Problem Samsung Android mobile phone FROM another device

Tags: android, connection, usb, device, samsung-mobile

Good morning,
I have a Samsung Android mobile phone, what I connect via an usb cable to another device (not pc).
For this case i have enabled usb debuging and the developer mode in android.

If I use another android mobile it works perfect, the other device is blinking and I can read out the device port by my android application. This "buggy" device cannot display the usb device port in my android phone and the bounded device is not blinking. For my opinion the device is not recognized by my phone. Is there anything else what I can change in the options or unblock? Is there some debug report oder anything else what i can look for what went wrong?

Thanks for your possible help

Comment: no idea for a solution?

Comment: Unclear what the 'usb device' is, if you wrote an app to connect to it use [adb over wifi](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+) and inspect the logcat.

Comment: The task is to connect via usb and it works in most android samsung phones. some not detect the device. F.e . a Samsung Galaxy S5 mini not working. The device is a thing with an embedded firmware software and don´t have any other possibility to connect with

Comment: any hint or solution?